# Complex Line Integral of absolute value of z

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How do we proceed for the following complex line integral?

$$\int\limits_\gamma |z|\:dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the half circular $|z|=1$, $0\leq \arg (z) \leq \pi$

taking $z=1$ as the initial point.

Any hints would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $z = e^{i\theta}$. The limits become $0$ to $\pi$

$|z| = 1$ and $dz$ = $ie^{i\theta}\:d\theta$

$$\int\limits_\gamma |z| \:dz = \int\limits_0^\pi ie^{i\theta} \:d\theta$$

Comment: Thank you.. one more question... that if the angle were $\frac{-\pi}{2} \leq \arg z \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and z = - i, was the initial point? we just need to change the limit of the integration by $\frac{- \pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$??

Comment: yes, you are right